# Return a object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm busy with a new language : C#. I can't figure out how to return a object in this method.... It's in a Database. I put in a gameID and then i want to return the Game of that GameID

Can someone help me?

**Method in GameController:**

```
public Game getGame(int gameID)
    {
        Game game = new Game();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();


            string selectQuery = "select * from game where game_id=@gameID";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameID", gameID);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                game.ID = dataReader.GetInt32("game_id");
                game.Naam = dataReader.GetString("gamenaam");
                //game.Genre.ID = dataReader.GetInt32("genre_id");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Ophalen van genres mislukt " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return game;


    }
```

**Model Game:**

```
public class Game
{
    public String Naam { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} (id = {1}) {2}", Naam, ID, Genre);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: No im using .net framework 4

Comment: Assuming you have a SQL Server database, the duplicate is spot on. For other platforms the syntax will be mostly the same.

Comment: Edited the text, can u help me?